# Creating a counter using R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a counter that keeps track of the amount     times a certain barcode number (for a tool) is input. Here is what I 
have tried:

```
myfunction <- function(Barcode.Number){
tool <- readline(prompt="Enter tool: ")
df1 <- df %>% filter(df$Barcode.Number == tool) %>% 
select(Type.Equipment, Location, REMARKS) 
if (tool == i){
df$Times.Used[i] <- i+1
}
return(df1)
 }
```

What I am trying to do with this is have an input value(barcode 
number), output with additional column information (Type.Equipment, 
Location, REMARKS), from my data frame, as well as adding to the 
counter column (Times.Used) whenever it is taken as an input. Thanks so much!

Here is some of the sample data that I have from the frame:
Barcode.Number, Equipment, Manufacture, TIMES.USED

4041, Flashlight, Surefire,

4044, Combo Pad Lock, Master,

4641, 3k Generator, Honda,

Hope that helps. As for calling the function and the output, I would just want to call it when I need to take an input. SO preferably I would run the program, the input statement would show up, and then once a barcode number is input it would run the function. No real output would necessarily be required, just an update to the data frame. Just a function that takes an input, and adds to that barcodes rows 'TIMES USED' column, so that it can be looked back at later to asses the amount of usage a certain thing has. Thank you!

Comment: It's unusual to have a function that depends on a certain data frame *not* have the data frame passed in as an argument. With the function as you have written it, it would be impossible to use if your data frame was named anything other than `df`. Also, since `Barcode.Number` is a input argument, presumably it is a variable, but `$` cannot be used with variables as you try to do with `df$Barcode.Number`. Then  you get to `if(tool == i)`, but `i` isn't defined anywhere. So there are a lot of problems.

Comment: Overall, I'm still a little confused about what you are trying to do. Can you share (a) a little sample data, (b) some examples of how you would want to call the function, and (c) the output you would expect from your sample inputs?

Comment: Hi Gregor, I apologize for the late response. I updated my post to add additional information. Hope it helps. Thanks so much for your help!